# Azure Web Deploy "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'."

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

I've been browsing the web for a couple hours now looking for an answer to my problem. I am trying to deploy a Web API on Azure Web App Service using VS2017. Everything builds and works fine when running locally but once deployed on Azure (through VS2017) I get this error:

> D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\roslyn\csc.exe

My project is an ASP.NET Web Application (Using Azure Web API template) .NET Framework 4.6.1. I use `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform Version=1.0.6.0`

I also made sure that csc.exe is located in:

`Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DeviceManagementAPI\DeviceManagementAPI\bin\roslyn`

Comment: Do you have code for this, and your desired output? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you ensure that it is set as `Copy Local = True`?

Comment: @Martin, I'd suggest rather than writing [Solved] in the title of the question. Mark one of the answers that helped you as accepted :)

Answer (score 4):

Just had the same problem and it seems it's a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/13) with `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` **1.0.6** and **1.0.7**.

Downgrading to **1.0.5** solves the problem.

Comment: Update, version 1.0.8 has been released and it has fixed my problem, though others are still reporting problems.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform to 1.08 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After a while I simply uploaded manually the roslyn file directly into the server through Kudu. It seems to solve the problem but I still don't know why it won't upload automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue might be caused by missing or incorrect relative **packages** path. If you're changing solution folder structure make sure all imports have proper path's to avoid missing **Roslyn** files.

Generally suggest to replace auto-generated `../../../packages/...` rabit hole with parameter which will point to correct **Nuget** folder.

```
<Import Project="$(NugetPackagesPath)\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('$(NugetPackagesPath)\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
```